# Nodejs return value request from promise bluebird to variable

Tags: node.js, promise, return-value, bluebird, freeze

I want to get multiple async urls, parse them and return value for continue code.

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const rp = require('request-promise');

var request1 = rp('https://www.wp.pl');
var request2 = rp('https://www.google.pl');
var request3 = rp('https://www.dell.com/support/home/pl/pl/pldhs1/product-support/servicetag/41H3D5J/diagnose');
//var request4 = ......

var output = Promise.all([request1, request2, request3])
    .spread(function (responseOfReq1, responseOfReq2, responseOfReq3) {
        console.re.log(responseOfReq1.split("\n")[0]);
        console.re.log(responseOfReq2.split("\n")[0]);
        console.re.log(responseOfReq3.split("\n")[2]);

        //parse result and return data

        return 'aaaaa'; //return data;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        if(err!='')
        console.re.error(err);
    });

console.re.info('done get urls');
console.re.debug(output);
```

console return `responseOfReq1`, `responseOfReq2`, `responseOfReq3` but execution code locked on Promise, and `console.re.info('done get urls');` doesn't do.

Where is problem?

Comment: @estus This is example for javascript, not for node. And my syntax is different from Your link

Comment: What do you mean by code locked on Promise?

Comment: @Baboo_ code in promise is excecuted, but after promise, `console.re.info('done get urls');` doesn't show, this mean that executing code don't go to this line. I know thah is `resovle` promise, but I don't know how use this in my code.

Comment: Node isn't a different language. It's a platform that uses Javascript. Answers cover all possible asynchronous calls, including promises and totally applicable to Node. You just need to read them. TL;DR: you cannot synchronously return a result to a variable from asynchronous request. Because it's **a**synchronous. `console` should reside inside `then`.

Comment: @estus this mean, that I cat run asynchronus process from main program, but I can't get result asynchronus proces in main program? You say `then`... Hmmm, maybe I can run asynchronus program and in `then` parse data and send data to browser

Comment: @estus there is an asynchronous handling problem for sure but it doesn't explain why `done get urls` is not displayed

Comment: @Peter have you tried using `console.log` instead of `console.re.info`?

Comment: *Hmmm, maybe I can run asynchronus program and in then parse data and send data to browser* - yes, that's how it's done. It's unknown what's `console.re` in your case. If it's custom console implementation then blame it on it.

Comment: @estus Yes, this is Console.re, because I have node on MyDevil.net server and node is running as process. When I run node from console, I have a lot of errors

Comment: You don't seem to understand that `Promise.all()` returns a promise.  The ONLY way to get the value out of that promise is to use `await` or `.then()` with that promise.  To use an asynchronously obtained value you have to use asynchronous ways of programming.  There are no other ways around it.

Comment: I must read about `await` and `.then()` method. I want in multiple intances get data from url (about 20 urls), and after get data from all request, parse them, and continue execute main program

Comment: `console.re.info('done get urls');` will "do" ***before*** all those `responseOfReq#`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. Ok now I know that I must parse result in `.spread`. But I know what is what